# How to change the default Django page to my own one?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django,and I followed a guidebook.I want to change the default Django page into my own one.It has took me 2 hours to solve this,and nothing worked.
The project is called learning_log,and the app is called learning_logs.
Here's what I'm trying to do:
1.add module learning_logs.urls:

```
"""
Definition of urls for learning_log.
"""

from datetime import datetime
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from app import forms, views
#added
from django.conf.urls import include, url
import learning_logs.views
from django.urls import path,re_path

app_name='learning_logs'
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('login/',
         LoginView.as_view
         (
             template_name='app/login.html',
             authentication_form=forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
             extra_context=
             {
                 'title': 'Log in',
                 'year' : datetime.now().year,
             }
         ),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='/'), name='logout'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #added
    re_path(r'',include('learning_logs.urls',namespace='learning_logs'))
    ]
```

To include the module,I've tried:

```
url(r'',include('learning_logs.urls',namespacec='learning_logs'))
path('',include('learning_logs.urls',namespacec='learning_logs'))
path('',include('learning_logs.urls'))
path('',learning_logs.urls)
path('',learning_logs.views)
```

But none of them worked.

2.Create urls.py in learning_logs.here's the code:

```
"""define learning_logs's url mode"""
from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import include,url

urlpatterns=[
    #homepage：
    re_path(r'(?P^$)',views.index,name='index')]
    #path('',include('learning_logs.views.index'))]
```

As you can see,I also tried many times.

3.Write views.py in learning_logs

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """homepage of learning logs"""
    return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')
```

4.write HTML document in learning_logs/templates/learning_logs/index.html

code skipped,for it never came up.

Here is my document tree:
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx1Ia.png)

What I want is that show my own homepage at localhost:xxxxx/

How to solve this?

Comment: is namespacec is spelling mistake ? and use re_path(' ',views.index,name='index')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's simple. just change this

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

to this

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', learning_logs.views.index, name='home'), #correct path to your index view
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do, why don't you just use:

```
urlpatterns =[
   path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

And change the name so it directs you to that home page instead?

E.g.

```
urlpatterns =[
   path('', views.learning_logs, name='learning logs'),
```

Also, since learning logs IS in the views file you shouldn't use

```
path('',learning_logs.views)
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer!This is a simple problem,but troubles me a lot.